# How to exclude a repeated values efficiently

Tags: numerics

I have been trying to exclude the repeated values in a list and in order to do this i used DeleteDuplicates but it didn't exclude all the repeated values. to give a better explanation what i did is enter code here

```
A= {3.34647, 0.833579, 1.04804, 1.03159, 1.03159, 1.05248, 1.04804, 
0.96958, 0.898022, 0.898022, 0.97556, 1.04804, 0.868071, 1.03159, 
1.05248, 1.03159, 1.35308, 1.03159, 1.35308, 0.868071, 1.05248, 
0.96958, 1.35308, 0.947005, 0.833579, 1.35308, 1.35308, 0.97556, 
0.954158, 1.03159, 1.35308, 0.868071, 0.947005, 0.96958, 1.03159, 
0.954158, 1.04804, 0.898022, 0.947005, 1.35308, 0.868071, 0.898022, 
0.97556, 3.34647};

re=DeleteDuplicates[{A}]
```

the result that I got is

> ```
> {3.34647, 0.833579, 1.04804, 1.03159, 1.03159, 1.05248, 0.96958, 
> 0.898022, 0.898022, 0.97556, 1.04804, 0.868071, 1.05248, 1.35308, 
> 0.868071, 0.96958, 0.947005, 0.833579, 1.35308, 0.97556, 0.954158, 
> 0.96958, 0.954158, 0.947005, 0.868071, 0.97556, 3.34647}
> ```

as you can see some of the repeated values were exclude and some of them not 
 so would you please tell me if  there is something wrong with my code or is there another command or another order that i can use to eliminate the repeated values

Comment: I corrected your code formatting but please take care of interpunction etc.

Comment: What about `DeleteDuplicates[A]`? The list `{A}` has only one element (`A`), hence has no duplicate.

Comment: If I scrape-n-paste your A and then DeleteDuplicates[A] I get far fewer results than you do. If I click on Details in the help for DeleteDuplicates and then click on SameQ and then click on Details in that I see that it will decide two numbers are the same if they differ only in the very last binary digit. But decimal numbers only show the first 6 digits by default. So I am thinking many of your numbers are very slightly different and thus are not eliminated by DeleteDuplicates, but look the same to you. Try FullForm[A] to see all the details and see if this explains why some were not deleted.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple machine float numerics problem. Try something like

```
data = 
  {3.34647, 0.833579, 1.04804, 1.03159, 1.03159, 1.05248, 
   1.04804, 0.96958, 0.898022, 0.898022, 0.97556, 1.04804, 0.868071, 
   1.03159, 1.05248, 1.03159, 1.35308, 1.03159, 1.35308, 0.868071, 
   1.05248, 0.96958, 1.35308, 0.947005, 0.833579, 1.35308, 1.35308, 
   0.97556, 0.954158, 1.03159, 1.35308, 0.868071, 0.947005, 0.96958, 
   1.03159, 0.954158, 1.04804, 0.898022, 0.947005, 1.35308, 0.868071, 
   0.898022, 0.97556, 3.34647};

Sort @ DeleteDuplicates[data, (Round[#1, 10^-6] == Round[#2, 10^-6]) &]
```

> ```
> {0.833579, 0.868071, 0.898022, 0.947005, 0.954158, 0.96958, 
>  0.97556, 1.03159, 1.04804, 1.05248, 1.35308, 3.34647}
> ```

Comment: `DeleteDuplicatesBy` is also a potentially simpler choice, too.